# Azure pipeline task AzureContainerApps environment variables in DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-apps

I have the 'AzureContainerApps@1' functioning and deploying. But each time the environment variables are reset (which i understand).

I also have a variable group, the key/values of this group needs to be passed into the container for the Node.js app to function.

My code below sets the build id, but the variable group has 50 values that need to be passed in with the same key/value.

Is there a smart way to do this so as not to have to edit the pipeline.yml file if a values is added to the variable group?

My task:

```
variables:
- group: cms-aeh-poc

     
task: AzureContainerApps@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.container_service_resource_manger_connection}}
      containerAppName: ${{parameters.container_app_name}}
      resourceGroup: ${{parameters.resource_group}}
      imageToDeploy: "${{parameters.container_reg_login_server}}/${{parameters.repository}}:$(Build.BuildId)"
      environmentVariables: BUILD_ID=$(Build.BuildId)
```

For example the variable group has these values:

APP_NAME = my lovely app
REGION = UK
BASE_DIR = /lovely/stuff

I need these AND the BUILD_ID passed in

Comment: So to clarify you are looking at having a set list of fixed params but then one additional that has a different value (the buildId) ?

Comment: Yes, I've added example to the question. I can see manually writing out 50 key/value pairs and editing that overtime as being the best way

Comment: If these are fixed and not secret you can store in the repo as a json file then read in to an array in a PowerShell task, append in the dynamic and secure items then use in this task.

Comment: Or you can leave in the group but use a powershell task to join together the fixed and dynamic then store in a variable to use in this task

Comment: Can you point me towards an example?

Comment: I can see someone else has given an example now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can read all variables in the variable group and pass them to environmentVariables of AzureContainerApps task.

To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can use the PowerShell script to run the Rest API: [Variablegroups - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to list all variable names in the variable group and add them to the string list.

Then you can define Pipeline variable to save the variable list and pass it to AzureContainerApps task.

For example:

```
variables:
 - group: cms-aeh-poc
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $token = "$(PAT)"
      
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{variablegroupid}?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
      
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json
      
      $string=""
      
      foreach($variablename in $response.variables.psobject.properties.name)
      {
      
        $env = "$variablename=`$($variablename`)"
        
      
        $string= -join("$string", " ", "$env")
        
      }
      
      echo $string
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=variablelist]$string"


- task: AzureContainerApps@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xx'
    xxxx
    environmentVariables: 'BUILD_ID=$(Build.BuildId) $(variablelist)'
```